# Why does SELECT * INTO x FROM a JOIN b take significantly greater time than total time of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a JOIN b & SELECT * INTO y FROM x?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, database-performance

I have 2 tables: `a` & `b`. Table `a` has around 1 million records whilst table `b` has around 50,000 records. Non-clustered index is defined on a column each in `a` & `b`. The 2 tables are joined based on these columns. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * INTO x
FROM a JOIN b ON a.cola = b.colb
```

The end result is around 2 million records. The query takes around 14 minutes to complete. However, if I try to do a `COUNT(*)`, instead of `SELECT...INTO`, the query takes less than a minute to complete.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM a JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col1
```

I assumed the remaining 13 minutes was due to I/O operations. So I ran another query which just took the previously inserted data from 'x' and inserted into 'y'.

```
SELECT * INTO y
FROM x
```

This query took 5 minutes to insert the 2 million rows of data. My question is then what is the reason the first query takes 14 minutes to complete, while the total time for the actual join & the independent insert of the same set of data is just 6 minutes. What is the reason for the remaining 8 minutes of execution time? Is there any way I can reduce this time?

I have looked at the actual execution plan for the 1st query. >95% of the time is used up in the INSERT operation. The INSERT operation just inserts the columns as is - there is no additional logic (like calculations, CAST, CASE...WHEN etc.). My database is already in BULK_LOGGED recovery mode, so these SELECT...INTO operations are minimally logged.

Comment: Because, with `SELECT * INTO x` SQL Server needs to obtain the value of **every** column for **every** row, for `SELECT COUNT(*)` it simply needs to know how many rows there are. They are completely different queries. Imagine if I asked you to count how many pages there are in a book, and I also asked you to copy the an entire contents of said book, page by page; do you really think you could do both as quickly/slowly?

Comment: It is wrong to assume that 95% of *estimated cost* = 95% of *time*. It is just an estimate of combined I/O and CPU cost. What are the wait types experienced during the operation? How did you confirm that you are getting minimal logging? This depends on more than just the database recovery model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is I/O operations.  The `JOIN` has to process *all* the data rather than just the row counts.  You are not taking this processing time into account.

Given the work that `JOIN` has to do, an additional read/write of the data seems about right.

Comment: Is there any step I can take to reduce this time?

Comment: @Ral'akkai -- Get a faster disk

Comment: @Ral'akkai So you want to write 2 million rows to disk quickly? I want to drive to work in 5 minutes instead of 30. I'll need a helicopter maybe, or quit my job and take one much closer to my house, but there's not much else I can do. In your case, you can write less data (whether it's number of rows, or fewer columns). Or get faster disk. Or both. But really the problem isn't just writing 2 million rows, it's also logging all of that information. You may be able to BCP data out and then get it back in with minimal logging. Delayed durability might also help.